# Warning: file_put_contents error in drupal

Tags: drupal

I  am getting following error when I am trying to upload an image to a block in Drupal. Could anyone help me on this?

"Warning: file_put_contents(/sites/all/modules/azexo_composer/azexo_elements/elements.js): failed to open stream: Permission denied in azexo_get_template_elements() (line 738 of /sites/all/modules/azexo_composer/azexo_composer.module)"

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Your web server user (apache?) don't have permission to write that file?!

Comment: Yes , but permissions are their

Answer (score 0):

you don't have permission for create file in directory.

you can create file in  sites/default/files directory